# Change image on dark mode (class) tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css, darkmode

I want to change my logo image when I switch to dark mode (I'm using classes on tailwind). Is there a chance to make it?

This is the hook I'm using to change the theme:

```
const useTheme = () => {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(localStorage.theme);
  const nextTheme = theme === "light" ? "dark" : "light";

  useEffect(() => {
    const rootElement = window.document.documentElement;
    rootElement.classList.remove(nextTheme);
    rootElement.classList.add(theme);
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
  }, [theme, nextTheme]);

  return [nextTheme, setTheme];
};
```

And this is my image that I want to change (if it helps):

```
<div className="flex flex-col">
  <Link
    to="/"
    className="flex px-5 gap-2 my-6 pt-1 w-190 items-center"
    onClick={handleCloseSideBar}
  >
    <img src="/img/logo.png" alt="logo" className="w-full" />
  </Link>
</div>;
```

Comment: Could you please add all the code? Or  preferably a link to the repository ?

Comment: Thx :-) Remember for the future! add .env to .gitigonre file ! ;-)

Comment: Have you guys solved it?

Answer (score 16):

You could just use the display property. Something like this in TailwindCSS:

```
<img class="block dark:hidden" src="./img/logolight.png">
<img class="hidden dark:block" src="./img/logodark.png">
```

I did the same on our docs.launchbrightly.com site, if you want a live example to inspect :-)